# Find the value from json where key is in another variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

suppose we have json object like,

```
  const land={
  water : "cool",
   air  : "heat"
}
```

now if key = "water";

how to find the value instead like this land.water;
just by key only and also without loop

just like

```
  console.log(land.key); //but its not working
```

please help me.. it took almost 4hrs but unable to find the solution.

Comment: try ``land[key]``

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable and use [square bracket notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781) to retrieve the property from `land`:

```js
const land= {
  water: "cool",
  air: "heat"
};
const h2o = "water";
console.log(land[h2o]);

// all keys from land
const [wtr, pfft] = Object.keys(land);
console.log(land[pfft]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`const land={
water : "cool",
air  : "heat"
}

console.log(land.water)`
It gives cool as the result.
You just have to use the key and you will get the value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const land = {
  water: "cool",
  air: "heat"
};
const h2o = "water";
console.log(land[h2o]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const land ={
water:'cool',
air:'heat'
}

let {water:someOtherName} = land

console.log(someOtherName)
```